# Jquery, Print number of occurrence of an json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to print

```
true: 5,
false: 3,
www.google.com: 4
```

in the console/alert to check how many time does the a specific value is present in the data.

below is my data

```
data = [
    {
        "active": true,
        "attributes": {
            "exclusiveBrand": true,
            "pickup": false
        },
        "availability": {
            "pickup": {
                "available": true,
                "availability": false,
                "checkStoresLink": {
                    "url": "www.google.com"
                }
            },
            "ship": {
                "available": false,
                "logoUrl": "www.google.com",
                "checkLink": {
                    "height": 470,
                    "targeting": "popup",
                    "url": "www.google.com",
                    "width": 530
                },
                "getItBy": {
                    "currentPrice": 109.99,
                    "availability": true,
                    "regionalAvailabilityEligible": true,
                    "imageUrl": "www.google.com"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards,
Satz

Comment: Is there a particular value or property you are wanting to count?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. In this case since you are encountering the values at different depths recursive `for key in object` loops is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, doesn't work yet, should be very close, but this is my first iteration:

```
function findNestedValues(arrayOfValues, nestedObject) {
  output = {};
  arrayOfValues.forEach(value => output[value.toString()] = 0);

  for (key in nestedObject) {
    currentVal = nestedObject[key];
    currentValStr = String(currentVal);
    if (typeof currentVal === 'object') {
      nested = findNestedValues(arrayOfValues, currentVal);
      for (subkey in nested) {
        output[subkey] += nested[subkey];
      }
    }
    else if (output.hasOwnProperty(currentValStr)) {
      output[currentValStr]++;
    }
  }

  return output;

}
```

(Known error is that `typeof` will return 'object' for objects, arrays, null, and functions, so I'll look up a better way to do that in a minute... but if your input can be quality controlled, this should work for now... Also, NaN will be equal here.)

Answer (score 0):

There is rather unexpected solution of this problem using `String.replace` method.

```
var data = [//initial data from OP
];
var anyVar = JSON.stringify(data); // we want string
var stat = {}; //here we collect result
var re=/(false|true|www\.google\.com)/g; //what we are looking for
anyVar.replace(re, function(m, pat){
  //this is the trick
  stat[pat] = (stat[pat] || 0) + 1; //count each captured pattern
  return m; //no need to change the string
});
console.log(stat); // Object { true=5,  false=3,  www.google.com=4}
```

### Update

A little more elaborated RegEx.

```
var re=/(?::\"?)(\bfalse\b|\btrue\b|www\.google\.com)(?:\/?\"?[,}])/g; 
//value follows after : and possible " (?: for non-capturing.
//the value may be closed by quot (") and followed by comma (,) or curly bracket (})
//this way "true love" and "false intends" are excluded.
```

Comment: Nice unexpected solution. It might have some unexpected behavior though. I.e. keys named like 'trueStory' will be counted as well for true. And there is no distinction between true and 'true'

Comment: What can stop from using `\btrue\b`?

Answer (score 0):

The comment from disso in a working example:

```js
var obj = data[0];
var countValInObj = function(obj,val1,val2){
 var count = [0,0];
 var checkObj = function(x){
  for (var key in x) {
   if(typeof x[key] == 'object'){
    checkObj(x[key]);
   } else if(x[key] === val1) {
    count[0]++;
   } else if(x[key] === val2) {
    count[1]++;
   }
  }
 }
 checkObj(obj);
 return count;
}
n = countValInObj(obj,true,false);
```